# Jackson xml (de)serialization with custom boolean format

Tags: jackson-dataformat-xml

I have xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ADDRESSOBJECTS>
    <OBJECT ID="1802267" NAME="SomeName" ISACTIVE="1" />
</ADDRESSOBJECTS>
```

and correponding classes in kotlin:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "ADDRESSOBJECTS")
class AddressingObjectCollection {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "OBJECT")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    open lateinit var objects: List<AddressingObject>
}
```

and

```
class AddressingObject : Serializable {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "ID")
    open var id: Long = 0

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "NAME")
    open lateinit var name: String

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "ISACTIVE")
    open var isActive: Boolean = false
}
```

when I try to deserialize I get error:

```
val deserialized = mapper.readValue(File(file).readText(), AddressingObjectCollection::class.java)
```

error:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `boolean` from String "1": only "true"/"True"/"TRUE" or "false"/"False"/"FALSE" recognized
```

How to tell jackson to (de)serialize this format properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose I use Json attributes:

```
@JsonProperty("ISACTIVE")
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "ISACTIVE")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomBooleanDeserializer::class)
open var isActive: Boolean = false
```

And CustomBooleanDeserializer:

```
class CustomBooleanDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Boolean>() {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Boolean {
        if (p?.currentTokenId() == JsonTokenId.ID_STRING){
            var text = p.text

            if (text == "1") return true
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

It works for me.